# Базы данных - сравнения (для разработчиков с опытом)

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, firebird, sphinx, mysql

Выбор базы данных, теперь это моя проблема N1

А вдруг думаю я чего то упустил

Много лет проработал с MySQL, ожидал от нее большего.

Теперь настало время найти что то более быстрое для работы с очень большим объемом данных.

В первую очередь хотел бы узнать какая из этих баз данных работает быстрее?
Можете написать свой вариант

MySQL

MongoDB

firebird

postgresql

mysql+sphinx

Мне нужно в первую очередь для работы с PHP

И нужна именно бесплатная

p.s.
Как вы думаете на чем работает ozon.ru? (это отдельный вопрос)

Comment: Как разработчик с, возможно, небольшим, но опытом, замечу одно. Инструмент выбирается уже для конкретной, хорошо сформулированной задачи. Сам же по себе же вопрос «что лучше, киянка или кувалда?» смысла не имеет, как и сравнения по малоопределенному признаку в духе «чем стучать удобнее?»

Они просто разные инструменты для задач разного характера.

Comment: вот например сколько времени впаривали Ruby

но он медленный и как бы я не старался обьяснить стороннику руби что руби мягко говоря что то удобное но кривое, он меня не поймет

но когда будет с чем сравнивать он согласится

Comment: > в пхп почти все задачи одинаковые

Шутите, что ли?

Задачи по работе с БД очень разные, потому что работа идет над разными, по своей природе, данными. Отсюда разные паттерны обращения, соотношения чтения-записи, разные методы хранения и обработки. Сравнивать БД «что быстрее» без указания этой специфики — бессмысленное занятие.

Ну, вот, memcachedb очень «быстрая», например. Но после того, как купившийся на «быстроту» горе-разработчик напишет самопальные индексы, агрегаты и прочий велопарк, который потребуется для решения его задач — выяснится, что все это уже совсем не так быстро работает.

Answer (score 4):

Ozon.ru [судя по всему](http://www.ozon.ru/context/job/?id=6374322) работает на MS SQL SERVER.

"Работает быстрее" без привязки к другим метрикам это трудный вопрос, на который врядли получится ответить правильно.

MongoDB работает *очень быстро*, до тех пор пока хватает оперативной памяти и она не уходит в своп. Кроме того из коробки она идет в не совсем безопасном режиме (отключенное журналирование) и возможно у вас будут проблемы с восстановлением данных при сбоях. При включении журналирования она становится значительно медленней. 
С другой стороны, она очень удобна и проста в использовании, как в плане разворачивания, так и в плане работы с ней *из кода*.

PostgreSQL менее распространена чем MySQL, но в последнее время больше радует (теперь есть поддержка json'а как типа данных), к тому же из коробки в нем есть аналитические запросы (привет, оракл), которых в MySQL иногда не хватает.

*Кстати есть еще [форки MySQL](http://habrahabr.ru/post/108104/): Percona и MariaDB, как там утверждают быстрее оригинального MySQL*

Comment: тут я соглашусь на все 100% с утверждениями по поводу PostgreSQL - очень вкусные вещь в последнее время предоставляет - вот я и перевел свои проекты с SQL Server-а на PostgreSQL... и постепенно осваиваю....

Answer (score 1):

оптимизируй запросы.
озон работает на мускуле тоже, только запросы оптимизированы и нагрузка разделена между серверами.